# "gulp serve" will return this error "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined"

Tags: node.js, gulp, nvm

I have 2 versions of node.js, as follow:-

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 17.1.0 (x64) and npm.
C:\Windows\System32>nvm list

    16.13.0
    8.16.2
```

Now i am trying to run `gulp serve` on this SPFx web part @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-enhanced-list-formatting .. but i got this error:-

```
C:\spfx-MyModalPopup>gulp serve
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:47:5
    at req_ (C:\spfx-MyModalPopup\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\spfx-MyModalPopup\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\spfx-MyModalPopup\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)

C:\spfx-MyModalPopup>nvm use 16.13.0
exit status 145: The directory is not empty.
```

so what is going on ? thanks

Comment: What's the version of Gulp?

Comment: @YasinBr `C:\react-enhanced-list-formatting>gulp -v` got
`CLI version: 2.3.0` &
`Local version: 4.0.2
`

Comment: @YasinBr also if you can see i got this message `Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 17.1.0 (x64) and npm.` inside the node.js CMD >> but when i tried to get the node.js versions this version 17.1.0 is not listed.. so i am confused..